# Journey Builder Wait

Tags: marketing-cloud

Can anyone explain me what exactly the „End Date“ option in wait activity within the Journey Builder does?

There is no official documentation about it.

Comment: Here is the documentation for a wait until specified date https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_wait_activity.htm&type=5 Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

There is 3 types of waiting activity:

1. Wait by duration
2. Wait until Date
3. Wait by atribute

Option 1 you use in case when you want to wait a specific period of time (minutes, hours, days, weeks or months).

Option 2 you choose a specific waiting date by filling End Date as End Time fields.

Option 3 you can use a date atribute from you data source to wait a specific period before or after this atribute.